# Centering text not working

Tags: html, css

From all my searches I seem to be using the right technique but the centering just isn't happening.

This is the code block from my .html file:

```
    <div id="section-movement" class="section-container">
        <div class="section-title">
            Movement <span class="center">*click entries for more details*</span><span class="float-right">limited by movement speed</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the entries in my .css file:

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}
```

The output should be the word 'movement' left aligned, the text 'click entries for more details', should be centered and the text 'limited by movement speed' should be right aligned. The left and right text work fine but the 'click entries for more details' text is not centering, it just immediately follows the 'movement' text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span` is an `inline` element by default. The way you use centering is *inside*  a `span` element, which doesn't do anything since it's inline.

You can use `<div>`s instead of `<span>`s, which are block elements (default width: 100%), but I don't know if this is what you imagine - in your current code you are trying to center some words which basically are part of a text paragraph...

It seems you want to distribute three parts of a sentence left, middle and right. You can put all three parts into DIVs or SPANs (in this particular case it won't matter since they all become flex items by the flex definition of their container) and add this rule for their parent element:

```
.section-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Here's the complete code:

```css
.section-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="section-movement" class="section-container">
  <div class="section-title">
    <span>Movement</span><span>*click entries for more details*</span><span>limited by movement speed</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can just use the center tag...?

So it would be:

<'center>

...Content you want centered...

<'/center>

But without the apostrophe's.

Comment: so why don't you delete the apostrophes (also from the word "apostrophes")? Plus: The `center` tag isn't valid anymore in HTML5: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

I made a minor update to your HTML and put the word "Movement" in a span that I floated left. I floated the span with a class of right to the right and added text-align: center to the div with a class of section-title that centered the span with a class of center.

Note that you don't need a text-align: center rule on the div with a class of center.

```
.section-title {
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
 float: right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eulloa/k7LL0byt/1/